# React+Redux - Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm trying to implement redux in my universal app, but I've some problems with redux.
I've this configureStore function:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';

export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
  const reduxRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
  let finalCreateStore;

  if (__DEVELOPMENT__ && __CLIENT__ && __DEVTOOLS__) {
    const { persistState } = require('redux-devtools');
    const DevTools = require('../containers/DevTools/DevTools');

    finalCreateStore = compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : DevTools.instrument(),
      persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/))
    )(createStore);
  }
  else {
    finalCreateStore = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);
  }

  const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);

  if (__DEVELOPMENT__ && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept(rootReducer, () => {
      store.replaceReducer(rootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

And then I've my rootReducer file that looks like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import environment from './environment';
import general from './general';
import alert from './alert';
import user from './user';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  environment,
  general,
  alert,
  user,
  routing: routerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

The problem is that I get this error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
I've googled and searched on StackOverflow(where there are some similar problems), but the answers doesn't works in my case.

So, what I'm doing wrong ? and why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `./general`, `./environment`, `./alert` and `./user` all have an `export default` that is a function?

Comment: @ivarni is like this: https://gist.github.com/inchr/60ddb797a659e7d34ae145122b1b3187 so: export default function nameReducer(){...}

Comment: Try using `console.log` on all of your reducers in the `rootReducer` file to see which one of them is not a function

Comment: @SamP are alla functions... https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbe8rfgefbykg3m/Screenshot%202016-05-05%2012.21.52.png?dl=0 and in console too says: [1] [Function: environment] [1] [Function: general] [1] [Function: user] [1] [Function: user] [1] [Function: routerReducer]

Comment: @Noah does the error occur before React is able to mount or afterwards?

Comment: How can I test it ? btw I see this error in browser console, after I load the page.

Comment: @SamP is correct that when I do console.log(rootReducer), it says: [Function: combination] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
finalCreateStore = compose(
    // you write more than one createStore here
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : DevTools.instrument(),
    persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/))
)(createStore);
```

Comment: I've already fixed(sorry I got a busy day and I forgot to reply here)...btw this was the problem.

Comment: Removing that extraneous `(createStore)` --- which I had copied from similar code but with different syntax --- was what solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import environment from './environment';
import general from './general';
import alert from './alert';
import user from './user'; 
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'


export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  environment: environment,
  general: general,
  alert: alert,
  user: user,
 routing: routerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Yes :( same error...(I've read this solution also on another post here on stackoverflow)